# React - Printing the array inside an array in response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, axios, response

I'm trying to print an array inside an array in the data from the response

This is the props I sent to the MovieCard component from the app.js file

```
  <MovieCard
    movies={movies}
    oneMovie={oneMovie}
    getMovieInfo={getMovieInfo}
    myApiFilmsResults={myApiFilmsResults}
  />
```

And this is response from api

Response

[image: 1]

As an example from the MovieCard component
I am able to print the year info with

```
{props.myApiFilmsResults.year}
```

and this is my MovieCard component

```
import React from "react";
import "./movieCard.css";

import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
  CardText,
  Button,
  CardGroup,
} from "reactstrap";

export default function MovieCard(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      
            ---- I WANT TO PRINT HERE ----
      <div>
        <CardGroup className="cardGroup">
          {props.movies.map((movie) => (
            <Card className="itemCard" key={movie.id}>
              <img src={movie.image} />
              <CardBody className="cardBody">
                <CardTitle className="movieTitle">{movie.title}</CardTitle>
                <CardSubtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                  {movie.id}
                </CardSubtitle>
                <CardText className="movieDesc">{movie.description}</CardText>
                <Button className="showMapBtn" onClick={props.getMovieInfo}>
                  Movie Info
                </Button>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardGroup>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but when I try to print the "directors" or "actors" in the response example with the .map function, I get the following error

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <MovieCard> component:

at MovieCard (http://localhost:3000/main.5d542bc37c2fcbffb78e.hot-update.js:32:25)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41:94)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: can you show us your MovieCard component?

Comment: i added MovieCard component

Comment: print actors, directors inside movie array like `{movie.actors.map(actor => ...)}`

Comment: like this way , i get same error

Comment: what do you get if you add <CardText>{movie.directors ? movie.directors.length : 'unknown'}</CardText>